# How can i open beamer any particular reference

Tags: beamer, cross-referencing

Question:

I have almost finished my beamer presentation. I wish to know that is there any way that by cliking on any particular reference we can access the same reference in .pdf format.

Please help me because this is very Important element for my presentation.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are the references online or in your computer? In both cases the answer is just using `hyperref`...

Comment: @campa Actually all references are in one folder in pdf files. One humble request please answer by illustration.

Comment: Can you please make a compilable minimal working example? Are the locations of your local files in your bib file?